# MsgPack packing of string values longer than 32 characters in python

Tags: python, objective-c, python-2.7, msgpack

I'm using MessagePack for developing a client SDK. I need to develop clients in java, ObjC and python while my server is in java. I don't have any problems with java and ObjC msgpack libraries but in python, when I pack a dictionary with string value longer than 31 characters, the packed data won't unpack in other languages. Trying to unpack the same in python works fine though and as long as the string length is less than 32, the inter operability is very fine too. The below is one python example that fails..

```
myPacket = {u"api_key":u"ad09739ac168ff2a199fb24eb4e24db8"}
msgPackedPacket = umsgpack.packb(myPacket)
```

the binary data generated for this is

```
<81a76170 695f6b65 79d92061 64303937 33396163 31363866 66326131 39396662 32346562 34653234 646238>
```

while if I covert a dictionary with same key values in ObjC, I get

```
<81a76170 695f6b65 79da0020 61643039 37333961 63313638 66663261 31393966 62323465 62346532 34646238>
```

The ObjC result unpacks fine and the python won't.. and you can note the 2 extra bytes in data from ObjC.

A properly working example as below

```
myPacket = {u"api_key":u"ad09739ac168ff2a199fb24eb4e24d"}
```

number of characters = 30 here.. and I get the following bytes in python

```
<81a76170 695f6b65 79be6164 30393733 39616331 36386666 32613139 39666232 34656234 65323464>
```

and for ObjC, I get the below bytes..

```
<81a76170 695f6b65 79be6164 30393733 39616331 36386666 32613139 39666232 34656234 65323464>
```

I'm sorry if I miss something obvious.. looking for any workarounds or suggestions as I am struck for more than a day..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it is supposed to be myPacket. Sorry!

Comment: Which platform are you *unpacking*  on?

Comment: @Tim I'm unpacking in ObjC.. The msgpack library in ObjC just returns a nil and won't print any error. I have also tried to unpack in java which says Invalid byte: -39

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When looking at what characters are encoded by the hexadecimal strings, you can see that the first one decodes to

```
'\x81\xa7api_key\xd9 ad09739ac168ff2a199fb24eb4e24db8'  # Python's version
```

while the second one decodes to

```
'\x81\xa7api_key\xda\x00 ad09739ac168ff2a199fb24eb4e24db8'  # ObjC's version
```

The third, 30 bytes long string, decodes to

```
'\x81\xa7api_key\xbead09739ac168ff2a199fb24eb4e24d'     # both versions
```

Intrigued by the problem, I googled for MsgPack's specs and came across [this](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md#formats-str).

Now things are getting clearer.

- `\x81` says that the following is a one-element map.
- `\xA7` says that the following is a seven-character string.
- `api_key` is that seven-character string.

So far, so good. Now the differences begin:

- `\xd9` says that a `str8` string follows. The byte after `\xd9` is `\x20` (`hex 20 == dec 32 == ASCII space`). It denotes the length of that string (32). That's what Python uses, correctly, because `str8` is usable for strings of up to 255 characters in length.
- `\xda` says that a `str16` string follows. The following two bytes are `\x00\x20` (`hex 0020` == `dec 32`, as before). They also denote the length of the following string (32 again). That's what ObjC does, apparently. This is just as legal from the spec's point of view, just a little wasteful (one wasted byte).
- For strings of less than 32 characters, both implementations use a `fixstr` type that encodes a length of 1-31 characters in the bitfield `101xxxxx` which becomes `\xbe` for a 30-character string (`bin 10111110`).

So it seems that all the serializations are correct, but the deserializer you're using can't handle the `str8` datatype used by Python's serializer. The [implementation guidelines](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md#impl) state that dut to format changes, not all releases support `str8`, so that serializers should provide a compatibility mode without it. Python's `msgpack` package doesn't, though.

**UPDATE:** Just a few hours after the [bug report](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/issues/156), the developer of [`msgpack-Python`](https://github.com/vsergeev/u-msgpack-python) has added a compatibility switch to force Python to create `str16` serializations instead of `str8`. Well done!

Comment: For Python, the umsgpack library takes in unicode characters and hence   used u"..." This difference in bytes happen only when the string length is more than 31. They are exactly same otherwise.

Comment: Can you provide an example that does work (so we can see what exactly changes between 31 and 32 characters)?

Comment: I have edited the question with a working example. Thanks for caring to reply.

Comment: @Ravi: You're welcome. Thanks for sharing this intriguing problem. You may have found a bug in the MsgPack decoder - see my edit.

Comment: Thanks a lot again! That was a great insight to me. I have filed a bug with MsgPack and here is the link.. https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/issues/156

Comment: @Ravi: I read a bit further and came [across this](https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack/blob/master/spec.md#upgrading-messagepack-specification). Apparently, the `str8` format is not necessarily supported by all deserializers. Are you using the most current version of each MsgPack package?

Comment: @Ravi: I added a suggestion for a workaround. Give it a try :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39585/discussion-between-ravi-and-tim-pietzcker)